# How to select custom area of image in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing

Before asking question let me clear that I have searched a lot before asking.

I want to select custom area selected by user to be extracted.

Like the blur apps where user can select his/her body by dragging a finger over his body and the other part of image is blurred.I am trying to extract the object that is selected by the user from the picture with gesture of tapping on that.Like moving his/her finger on the object and app should detect the object and I can use that portion of the image.
I somehow managed to know that it can be done via bitmap,but don't know where to learn that.I have searched for the tutorials but in vain

I have viewed this tutorial but it does select the object based on the color,but I want selection based on user's gesture
https://hacking-ios.cocoagarage.com/uiimage-pixel-play-extension-in-swift-7c6fe90396b6#.eu19rxppp

Comment: You will likely get a negtive response because of the lack of detail in your question. What have you tried already? drawing a region as a selection from a tap / gesture is not very accurate and selecting objects in images is alot more difficult, you usually need some skills in computer vision. Apps such as image editing apps that let you blur the background will usually have very complex selection logic in them. Far too much involved to explain here

Comment: I have searched about opencv usage in swift but there is not tutorial.As I am a struggling developer,I try to learn all the things from the internet.So kindly help.I want to know what will be the best way to do that.either with computer vision or with gesture algorithm.And please give me direction to do either of them.As I could not find tutorials on either of them.

Comment: Please, state clearly what you a trying to achieve.